# Scatter plot of pair coordinates, annotated with pandas DataFrame index name for labels

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, annotations, scatter-plot

For a two-column pandas DataFrame, whose rows contain a pair of two values that belong to one another as x-y coordinates, how can a 2D plot be generated such that each pair of coordinates are given an annotated text label equal to the `index` name for that row?

[image]

for example, coordinate (`0.983801`, `0.0155373`) should appear as a single dot in the plot and annotated with `AXP`. Similar with the remaining rows, each uniquely named

The DataFrame was constructed from two 1-dimensional numpy arrays `a` and `b`, while the labels are a list of equal length to both:

```
#columns labeled on next line since the transpose of index arg is columns
df = pd.DataFrame(np.vstack((a,b)),index=['pe','jsc']).T 
df.index = labels #row labels
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
# sample data
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(4,2), columns=['pe','jsc'], index=list('abcd'))

plt.scatter(df['pe'], df['jsc'])
for idx, row in df.iterrows(): 
    plt.text(row['pe'], row['jsc'], idx)
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: this works. how can I control the distance between the dot and label so that they don't overlap?

Comment: @develarist you can add offsets to `plt.text`: `plt.text(row['pe']+0.03, row['jsc']+0.03, idx)`. Play with the offset.

Comment: i don't think `df.iterrows` is maintaining the corresponding order of the indexes to datapoints as how they appear in the DataFrame. The plot labels and data points don't correspond to the original data

Comment: @develarist yes it does. That's the whole point of `iterrows`. If you think the order is incorrect, you should review your creation of dataframe.

Comment: ok nevermind, I had to use `df.sort_values(by=` instead

Comment: why isn't there `df.itercols()` for iterating over columns instead?

Comment: It’s just `for col_name in df: col=df[col_name]`